# Wordpress installed site theme gave an safety alert on some page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My colleague has installed a wordpress theme for our project and asked me to update the content on that site. so i did the same.

But unfortunately after i updated the site, he was checking the dashboard on his computer, hence it gave an error saying

***"Deceptive site ahead, 
Attackers in this site may trick you on doing dangerous things... and so on.."***

Now he is blaming me on making this theme vulnerable.

But i just updated the content only by opening the dashboard in my laptop.

Can anyone let me know how this happened.

Please find the attached image for reference of error..

[warning error given by the site on its dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSv5J.png)